# Erdős-Rényi network

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I write a command that
generates an Erdős-Rényi network of 100 nodes in which the probability of a link to exist is p.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Rényi_model) and the documentation say `RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[100, p]]` is it.

Comment: If you type "erdos renyi" into the documentation search box, you will get the answer immediately.

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily found in the documentation by searching for "erdos renyi". See [`BernoulliGraphDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BernoulliGraphDistribution.html):

```
RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[100, p]]
```

It is good to note that the random graph model studied by Erdős and Rényi prescribed the exact number of edges, `m`, not the probability of connecting two vertices. This kind of random graph can be generated with `RandomGraph[{n,m}]`. Today both models are often referred to as "the Erdős–Rényi model".